# Function Inside HTML Input Range - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have javascript code to add a row to a table for each element of an array. The row contains a slider input and a cell that will show the slider's value. My function showVal is meant to update the cell containing the sliders value. Any ideas why this may not be working? Thanks!

```
var showVal = function(newVal){
   $('#sliderTable tbody tr:last-child td:last-child').html(newVal);
};

var sliderCreate = function(array1,array2){
   for (i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
     $('#sliderTable tbody').append('<tr><td>HI</td><td>Bye</td><td></td></tr>');
     $('#sliderTable tbody tr:last-child td:first-child').html(array1[i] + ': ');
     $('#sliderTable tbody tr:last-child td:nth-child(2)').html('<input type="range" oninput="showVal(this.value)" min="0" max="'+ initCheckVal +'">');
     $('#sliderTable tbody tr:last-child td:last-child').html(array2[i]);
   }
};
```

Comment: did you include the initial table tags?  that could easily trip you up :)

Comment: Inline html attribute event handlers can only call global functions. Is `showVal()` in the global scope?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the full context of your code, but if you're not seeing the slider at all, your problem could be caused by `initCheckVal` being undefined. I don't see where you have defined it, so I definitely would check that first.

Javascript doesn't like to string concatenate variables which are undefined (it can't), so if `initCheckVal` doesn't have a value set on the first iteration of the loop, you would not be seeing any of the HTML that you are trying to concatenate into the TD.